# Capitlization of A Named Experiment

Tags: grammar, capitalization

I have an experiment which we call 'the krypton experiment'.  In referring to the krypton experiment, should it be capitalized?

e.g.
The Krypton Experiment was used as a source of benchmark data.

or

The krypton experiment was used as a source of benchmark data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if *Krypton* is a proper noun, and then only *Krypton*, not *experiment*.

**The krypton experiment was used as a source** – if krypton is an element.

**The Krypton experiment was used as a source** – if based on the process of Professor Krypton.

Compare:

[**the Stanford prison experiment**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_prison_experiment)

Capitalization exceptions are the title of a paper or film or software, or just before establishing an acronym: The Stanford Prison Experiment (SPE)

Also see the names of specific [benchmark tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)#Industry_standard_(audited_and_verifiable)). The word "benchmark" is uncapitalized except where it is part of a product name.

Comment: What's the general rule?